# Basic Controller is not called and getting 404 Error in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Same question has answers in below links as well but it all did not solve the issues

[Spring mvc controller is not calling getting 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506294/spring-mvc-controller-is-not-calling-getting-404)

[Controller is not called in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688731/controller-is-not-called-in-spring-mvc)

[Spring MVC controller 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100246/spring-mvc-controller-404)

[Spring MVC Controller not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700433/spring-mvc-controller-not-called)

[Spring MVC - Controller method not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044429/spring-mvc-controller-method-not-getting-called)

Basic Controller is not called and getting 404 Error in spring MVC.
Is there any mistake in config of spring mvc ?

Web.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>XMLBasedMVC</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatchServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

XML based Spring Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="bridge"/>
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "webapp/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Bridge.java

```
package bridge;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
impor[![enter image description here][1]][1]t org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Bridge{

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getWelcomePage() {
        System.out.println("Called to controller");
        return "Welcome";
    }
}
```

The folder structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQy1m.png

The URL formed is
http://localhost:8080/XMLBasedMVC/

and the controller is not called and the **"Called to controller"** is printed in console

I am using maven for the spring jars, hence following the webapp>WEB-INF> folder structure

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>XMLBasedMVC</groupId>
  <artifactId>XMLBasedMVC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>14</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your jsp folder with files is located INSIDE WEB-INF not outside, and after that change your InternalViewResolver bean to something like

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
   <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Also I think that your web.xml should be just not have webapp there but just

```
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
```